# Cordova stuck on adding it to project

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

Whenever I run "cordova build ios", I get this.

```
Discovered plugin "de.appplant.cordova.plugin.local-notification" in config.xml. Adding it to the project
```

It goes through successfully sometimes though, but most of the times it is stuck and I have to retry it multiple times,taking so much time. any idea to resolve this or anyone ever faced this?

Answer (score 1):

ah sorry, I needed to add "sudo" all the time. It never gave me error though.